# Can I instantiate a module multiple times in one Racket program?

Tags: module, racket

Let's say I have the following file called `my-mod.rkt`.

```
#lang racket ;; my-mod.rkt
(displayln "Module ran")
```

I can obviously run this file by instantiating the module in the repl or another script:

```
(require "my-mod.rkt")
```

Which prints out `Module ran`.

However, if I cannot run the module twice this way. If for example, I require `my-mod.rkt` twice:

```
(require "my-mod.rkt")
(require "my-mod.rkt")
```

The module only gets instantiated once. Which is normally what you want for the purposes of requiring, but in this case instantiating the module has a side effect I'd like to preserve.

Obviously I could use `find-exe` to run this in another subprocess:

```
(require compiler/find-exe)
(system* (find-exe) "my-mod.rkt")
```

However then I'm running this program in another OS level process, which is not what I want to do.

So, can I instantiate a module twice in the same Racket program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can instantiate a Racket module twice in the same program. You can do this by changing your `current-namespace` and using `namespace-require`.

The following program, for example, will require the `my-mod.rkt` module twice:

```
#lang racket
(define ns (current-namespace))
(parameterize ([current-namespace (make-base-namespace)])
  (namespace-require "my-mod.rkt"))

(parameterize ([current-namespace (make-base-namespace)])
  (namespace-require "my-mod.rkt"))
```

And running this program will print out `Module ran` twice:

```
Module ran
Module ran
```

Note that you are doing this in two separate namespaces, and so anything imported from the module will be different in both cases. You are most likely to run into this problem if you are using `namespace-attach-module` to move the module from one namespace to another.

Also note that because you are using `current-namespace` to change the namespace, any submodules you have declared in the current module will no longer be visible. This only works because `my-mod.rkt`is in another file, if it was a submod you would not be able to do this.